# plot data from .txt or.tbl file

Tags: python, plot, import

I want to take data from a text file (or .tbl file) and plot the data from two of the columns in the file.I get the error- "EOL while scanning string literal" I have tried something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.loadtxt('uid.txt',
dtype = {
    'names':
        ('HJD', 'RELATIVE_DATE', 'PHASE',
        'RELATIVE_FLUX', 'RELATIVE_FLUX_UNCERTAINTY', 'RELATIVE_FLUX_WITHOUT_SYSTEMATICS',
        'DIFFERENCE_DATA_VS_MODEL', 'MODEL_FIT', 'MODEL_FIT_WITHOUT_SYSTEMATICS', 'AIRMASS'),
    'formats': ('f64', 'f64', 'f64', 'f64', 'f64', 'f64', 'f64', 'f64', 'f64', 'f64')
})

x = data['PHASE']
y = data['RELATIVE_FLUX_WITHOUT_SYSTEMATICS']


xlabel('orbital phase')
ylabel('flux')

plot(x, y, 'go')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Please reformat code and provide full traceback with your error

Answer (score 0):

I would recommed to use `pandas.read_csv()` or numpys `np.genfromtxt()` method instead, whereby `pandas` method is much faster for huge amounts of data. For documentation look here:https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html and here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html. Furthermore its hard to figure out where your Error comes from without any knowledge about your data.